# Semantics of Verilog >> operator applied to nets

Tags: operators, verilog, semantics

I'm trying to figure out a subtle detail of the semantics of the >> operator in Verilog. I haven't found anything relevant in the LRM or any other online reference/tutorial material.

As an example, suppose I want to convert binary to Gray code and back again. For binary-to-Gray, it's pretty straightforward:

[image: binary to gray logic]

```
wire [3:0] bin;
wire [3:0] gray;

assign gray[3] =          bin[3];
assign gray[2] = bin[3] ^ bin[2];
assign gray[1] = bin[2] ^ bin[1];
assign gray[0] = bin[1] ^ bin[0];
```

Of course, the assignments can be reduced to

```
assign gray = bin ^ {1'b0, bin[3:1]};
```

Or even just

```
assign gray = bin ^ (bin >> 1);
```

However, going in the opposite direction is a little different. This involves a recurrence relationship, in which the computation of each bit relies on the previous result:

[image: gray to binary logic]

```
assign bin[3] =          gray[3];
assign bin[2] = bin[3] ^ gray[2];
assign bin[1] = bin[2] ^ gray[1];
assign bin[0] = bin[1] ^ gray[0];
```

I can write this as

```
assign bin = gray ^ {1'b0, bin[3:1]};
```

But can I take the final step and write

```
assign bin = gray ^ (bin >> 1);
```

Obviously, that would never work in any software programming language. But to me as a hardware designer, these are all exactly equivalent in terms of the hardware connections that they describe. But which way will simulation and synthesis tools interpret it?

I'm about to go off and try a few simulators to see what happens, but I would appreciate a pointer to a definitive reference — even if it ends up being "unspecified" or "implementation-dependent".

---

Figures borrowed from [here](http://verilogcodes.blogspot.com/2017/10/4-bit-binary-to-gray-code-and-gray-code.html)

Comment: why did you think that `it would never work in any software programming language`? it is an absolutely normal code for both software language and verilog. There is nothing unspecified or implementation dependent in there. So, what is your question?

Comment: @Serge: In software, the recurrence wouldn't happen -- instead, a snapshot of the value of `bin` would be taken, shifted and then XOR'd with `gray`. That isn't what the statements above actually describe.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in simulation and synthesis. Recursion is fine as long as there is a statically deterministic number of recursions.